# Formula to extract value before specific text and after comma or beginning of original cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, string

I'm trying to extract statistics from a single cell `65 Rush Yds, 1 Rush TD, 1 Fum Lost, 105 Rec Yds, 1 Rec TD` to individual columns Rush Yds: `65` Rush TD: `1` Fum Lost: `1` Rec Yds: `105` Rec TD `1`

Extracting TDs was pretty straight forward using MID() since I knew it would always be only a single digit 2 spaces ahead using the formula

```
=IF(ISERROR(MID(A3,FIND("Pass TD",A3)-2,1)),0,MID(A3,FIND("Pass TD",A3)-2,1))
```

What I'm struggling with is extracting Rec Yds and Rush Yds as they can be anywhere from 1-3 digits (1-999) as well as in the middle of the original cell, or at the beginning.

[Here is a picture of what I'm trying to create a table for.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ttarV.jpg)

Comment: Plzz [edit] your post & add the Screen shot since is bit confusing, will help us to fix it !

Comment: Could you provide a sample here?

Comment: My apologies, I wrote this in a hurry last night.  I've added a picture and updated the description a little bit

Comment: Would [splitting the data into columns](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/split-text-into-different-columns-with-the-convert-text-to-columns-wizard-30b14928-5550-41f5-97ca-7a3e9c363ed7) be a helpful solution? It could at least serve as a starting point. Use a comma as a delimiter to get columns like `65 Rush Yds` and `1 Rush TD` then use a formula to extract everything before the first space as a number and everything after as text.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this: (assume there's only comma and space to separate data)

eg, to find `Rec Yds` in A2 `65 Rush Yds, 1 Rush TD, 1 Fum Lost, 105 Rec Yds, 1 Rec TD`

1. Find the target string index and trim it there, (notice there's space(s) at the end), then trim all spaces at two ends of the result, you'll get `65 Rush Yds, 1 Rush TD, 1 Fum Lost, 105`

   formula: `=TRIM(LEFT(A2,FIND("Rec Yds",A2)-1))` (let's put it in B2)
2. Replace all comma(,) with space, you'll get `65 Rush Yds  1 Rush TD  1 Fum Lost  105`

   formula: `=SUBSTITUTE(B2, ",", " ")` (let's put it in B3)
3. Replace every single space with a lot of spaces (here we use 10 spaces), you'll get `65          Rush          Yds                    1          Rush          TD                    1          Fum          Lost                    105`

   formula: `=SUBSTITUTE(B3, " ", REPT(" ", 10))` (let's put it in B4)
4. Get 10 charactors from right side, you'll get        `105`:

   formula: `=RIGHT(B4, 10)` (let's put it in B5)
5. Trim both sides, you'll get the final result `105`

   formula: `=TRIM(B5)`

[image]

Then you can combine all those formula into one (it may seem complex and ugly) add add some error checking

The number you extract is less than 5 digits, so you can use 5 or more spaces in step 3 and take the same number of chars in step 4. (here we used 10)

Comment: This works great, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you have Windows Excel 2013+ with the `FILTERXML` function, you can split the string and then check `C1:I1` for the appropriate component.

- Ensure your labels in Row 1 are the same as the "labels" in your stats string.  (or use a Helper row if that is not possible)

```
C2: =SUBSTITUTE(IFERROR(FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE($B2,",","</s><s>") & "</s></t>","//s[contains(.,'" &C$1 & "')]"),0),C$1,"")
```

[image]

*Note that in the above results screenshot, `Fumbles` is zero. That is because there is no `Fum Lost` column. You could add a column with that name, or you could use other techniques depending on exactly what you want for a result*